# How do I assign a drag function / listener to multiple elements?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a page with multiple draggable divs and am looking for a way to finesse my code.

The only way I would know how to apply this JS to each id is to copy & paste the whole block of JS code 4 times and change the id but I know there must be a more efficient way, however, I am not very familiar with JS.

My initial thought was doing something like this

```
dragElement(document.getElementById("draggable", "draggable2", "draggable3", "draggable4"));
```

But it doesn't work. How can I achieve what I want in a more efficient way?

Here is my code

```
<div id="draggable"><div id="draggableimg"></div></div>
<div id="draggable2"><div id="draggable2img"></div></div>
<div id="draggable3"><div id="draggable3img"></div></div>
<div id="draggable4"><div id="draggable4img"></div></div>
```

JS

```
//Make the DIV element draggable:
dragElement(document.getElementById("draggable"));
var _curDragEle = "";
function dragElement(elmnt) {
var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "img")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "img").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
} else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
}

function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    _curDragEle = this;
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
}

function elementDrag(e) {
    _curDragEle.classList.remove("dragstart")
    _curDragEle.className = _curDragEle.className + " dragstart";
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault();
// calculate the new cursor position:
  pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
  pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
  pos3 = e.clientX;
  pos4 = e.clientY;
// set the element's new position:
  elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
  elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
}

function closeDragElement() {
    var k = document.querySelectorAll(".dragstart")
    for(var i=0; i < k.length;i++){
        k[0].classList.remove("dragstart")
    }
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget `id`s, they lead to exactly the type of problem you are facing. Instead, give all the draggable elements a common class. Then gather all the elements up and loop over them.

```js
// Gather all the draggable elements up into a collection
let draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable");

// Loop over the collection
draggables.forEach(function(el){
  dragElement(el);
});

function dragElement(el){
  console.log(el + " is now draggable!")
}
```

```html
<div class="draggable"><div id="draggableimg"></div></div>
<div class="draggable"><div id="draggable2img"></div></div>
<div class="draggable"><div id="draggable3img"></div></div>
<div class="draggable"><div id="draggable4img"></div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The only thing is I don't know how to correctly combine this with my current JS code to create the same effect

Answer (score 0):

So I will simplify the question a bit and provide a simple answer that I think solves your issue. "How do I assign a drag function / listener to multiple elements?"

Basically, IDs must be unique, but you can get elements of the page in bulk by referencing their tags (i.e. "DIV") or class names. It's safer to use classnames. Here's an example that can help your issue.

HTML

```html
<div class="draggable-div" id="div1"><img /></div>
<div class="draggable-div" id="div2"><img /></div>
<div class="draggable-div" id="div3"><img /></div>
<div class="draggable-div" id="div4"><img /></div>
<div class="draggable-div" id="div5"><img /></div>
```

JS

```
function onDragEventHandler(e) {
  var div = e.target;
  // event code to drag here
}

var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable-div');
divs.forEach(function(elem,index) = {
  elem.addEventListener('mousemove', onDragEventHandler)
})
```